# What's wrong with this iterating over a collection code?

Tags: vba

I want to pass the items from ListBox1 to ListBox2, and delete them from LisBox1. It throws a null exception at "lb2.Items.Add(item)" but can't find out why. It works fine with just one item though

I tried doing a "for each item in lb1.items... lb2.items.add(item) + lb1.items.remove(item)" but it wouldn't work for you can't modify a list while iterating over it or an exception will be thrown. Also tried other different approaches but couldn't make it work

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If lb1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim itemsAPasar((lb1.Items.Count - 1)) As Object 
        For Each item In lb1.Items 
            itemsAPasar(UBound(itemsAPasar)) = item  
        Next
        For Each item In itemsAPasar
            lb2.Items.Add(item) 
        Next
        For Each item In itemsAPasar
            lb1.Items.Remove(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you only add to the last element in the array; everything < UBound is nothing.  All you need is `lb2.Items.AddRange(lb1.Items)` and `lb1.Items.Clear()`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you could simplify your approach a bit...

```
Dim itemsToMove = lb1.Items.ToList()
For Each item in itemsToMove
    lb1.Items.Remove(item)
    lb2.Items.Add(item)
Next
```